# Javers - org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR: given javaClass is mapped to ValueObjectType, expected EntityType

Tags: java, spring-boot, javers

I am getting below error: and I am working with **Spring Boot Mongo Javers**.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringbootJaVersApplication.main(SpringbootJaVersApplication.java:28) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR: given javaClass 'class com.example.model.Car' is mapped to ValueObjectType, expected EntityType
    at org.javers.core.metamodel.type.TypeMapper.getJaversManagedType(TypeMapper.java:188) ~[javers-core-5.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.javers.core.metamodel.object.GlobalIdFactory.createInstanceId(GlobalIdFactory.java:115) ~[javers-core-5.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.javers.core.metamodel.object.GlobalIdFactory.createFromDto(GlobalIdFactory.java:128) ~[javers-core-5.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.jql.FilterDefinition$IdFilterDefinition.compile(FilterDefinition.java:27) ~[javers-core-5.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.jql.JqlQuery.compile(JqlQuery.java:120) ~[javers-core-5.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.jql.QueryCompiler.compile(QueryCompiler.java:16) ~[javers-core-5.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.jql.SnapshotQueryRunner.queryForSnapshots(SnapshotQueryRunner.java:30) ~[javers-core-5.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.javers.repository.jql.QueryRunner.queryForSnapshots(QueryRunner.java:44) ~[javers-core-5.3.4.jar:na]
    at org.javers.core.JaversCore.findSnapshots(JaversCore.java:191) ~[javers-core-5.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.example.SpringbootJaVersApplication.withJavers(SpringbootJaVersApplication.java:54) [classes/:na]
    at com.example.SpringbootJaVersApplication.run(SpringbootJaVersApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Data in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0602e476e79c53f06f1d6b"),
    "commitMetadata" : {
        "author" : "unauthenticated",
        "properties" : [],
        "commitDate" : "2019-06-16T14:20:44.465",
        "commitDateInstant" : "2019-06-16T08:50:44.465Z",
        "id" : NumberLong(1)
    },
    "globalId" : {
        "valueObject" : "com.example.model.Car"
    },
    "state" : {
        "horsePower" : NumberLong(670),
        "year" : "2015",
        "model" : "488",
        "id" : "5d0602e476e79c53f06f1d6a",
        "brand" : "Ferrari"
    },
    "changedProperties" : [ 
        "horsePower", 
        "year", 
        "model", 
        "id", 
        "brand"
    ],
    "type" : "INITIAL",
    "version" : NumberLong(1),
    "globalId_key" : "com.example.model.Car/"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0602e476e79c53f06f1d6d"),
    "commitMetadata" : {
        "author" : "unauthenticated",
        "properties" : [],
        "commitDate" : "2019-06-16T14:20:44.574",
        "commitDateInstant" : "2019-06-16T08:50:44.574Z",
        "id" : NumberLong(2)
    },
    "globalId" : {
        "valueObject" : "com.example.model.Car"
    },
    "state" : {
        "horsePower" : NumberLong(800),
        "year" : "2015",
        "model" : "488",
        "id" : "5d0602e476e79c53f06f1d6a",
        "brand" : "Ferrari"
    },
    "changedProperties" : [ 
        "horsePower"
    ],
    "type" : "UPDATE",
    "version" : NumberLong(2),
    "globalId_key" : "com.example.model.Car/"
}
```

Car.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Car {
    private String id;
    private String brand;
    private String year;
    private String model;
    private Long horsePower;

    public Car(String brand, String year, String model, Long horsePower) {
        super();
        this.brand = brand;
        this.year = year;
        this.model = model;
        this.horsePower = horsePower;
    }
}
```

For the below code getting error

```
QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.byInstanceId((Object) "5d0602e476e79c53f06f1d6d", Car.class);
        List<CdoSnapshot> cdoSnapshots = javers.findSnapshots(jqlQuery.build());
        cdoSnapshots.sort((o1, o2) -> -1 * (int) o1.getVersion() - (int) o2.getVersion());
        for (CdoSnapshot cdoSnapshot : cdoSnapshots) {
            System.out.println(cdoSnapshot);
        }
```

Comment: If you think you found the bug, you can report it here https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#guidelines-for-bug-reporting (remember to follow Guidelines for Bug Reporting)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please share java version of the same ? Mostly looking for  Spring Data Javers of Spring

Comment: https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-core/src/test/java/org/javers/core/cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue myself. I should have annotated Car class with `@Document` at class level and `@Id` at the filed level in order to create `GlobalId_key` with the persisted primary key of the document.

This simply solved my issue. In my new example, with the below code works!

```
List<Person> persons = personRepository.findAll();

        Person p = persons.get(0);
        p.setName("Ravi");
        personRepository.save(p);

        JqlQuery query = QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(persons.get(0).getId(), Person.class).build();
        List<CdoSnapshot> shadows = javers.findSnapshots(query);
        for (CdoSnapshot cdoSnapshot : shadows) {
            System.out.println(cdoSnapshot);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually register your entity in Javers. Your entities must have an ID property annotated with `org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.Id`

```
@Bean
public Javers javers(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate, JaversProperties javersProperties) {
    return JaversBuilder.javers()
        .(...) // your config here
        .registerEntities(YourEntityClass.class, AnotherEntity.class) // here you register entities
        .build();
}
```